# How to have a bordered text in tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I need the text to have a black border.

I tried this,

```
  <div className="font-bold text-2xl text-white outline-4">
    Hello
  </div>
```

But it doesn't seem put a border to the text.

Comment: Use the `border-2` class. "2" can be replaced by `4`, `8`, etc.

Comment: That bring border around the text like a div. But need a text outlined in black @Yousaf

Comment: @SaiKrishnadas Could you be more precise about the goal ? How is this supposed to look like? Maybe image resolve the problem better.... ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found a custom tailwind drop shadow yields the best result:

```
drop-shadow-[0_1.2px_1.2px_rgba(0,0,0,0.8)]
```

Just adjust the pixel values and intensity, and use as standard tailwind attribute.

This even works on svgs.

[You can check out what an example looks like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs7N1.png)

Answer (score 8):

I had this issue as well, but I did not feel that the existing answers gave me a solution that follows Tailwind's utility-first approach.

Instead of creating custom css for a specific element, instead we should create a new tailwind utility class for this purpose.

To do that we alter the main.css tailwind file that holds our configuration and use the @layer base selector.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  .font-outline-2 {
    -webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;
  }
  .font-outline-4 {
    -webkit-text-stroke: 4px black;
  }
}
```

This allows us to reference our new class anywhere in our project alongside default tailwind classes, and it additionally works with Tailwind state selectors.

```
<h1 class="text-2xl font-bold font-outline-2 hover:font-outline-4">
  Works as expected
</h1>
```

Comment: this works well, but the downside is that the stroke takes away from the width of the text.

Answer (score 6):

Tailwind does not support it yet out of the box, you need to customize your CSS. Either use the experimental *[text-stroke](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke)* property, which is not very well supported so I don't recommend it, maybe later, or:

Use text-shadow that works pretty well.

```
h1 {
  color: white;
  text-shadow:
   -1px -1px 0 #000,  
    1px -1px 0 #000,
    -1px 1px 0 #000,
     1px 1px 0 #000;
}
```

Comment: Using text-shadow on paragraph text makes it harder to read. Best on headings and larger text content

Comment: Just as an update, now -webkit-text-stroke property is supported by all major browsers.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and couldnt find a decent solution.
So I came up with a very ugly solution: putting the text in a (disabled) button, this way I was able to put a border around the text only.